# Unzip .tbz compression format in C#

Tags: c#, unzip

The title pretty much states it.

Is there a way for me to unzip .tbz files in C#? Either using a third party library or just using normal libs to unzip .tbz files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tbz file is a tar + bzip2 compression archive.

You can try this open source [library](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/).

> #ziplib (SharpZipLib, formerly NZipLib) is a Zip, GZip, Tar and BZip2
>   library written entirely in C# for the
>   .NET platform.

Comment: Turns out the SharpZipLib doesnt extract .tbz files very consistently as it often leaves out the last few kilobytes

Anymore solutions? I'm considering scripting and then calling the program to execute script for extract off of 7zip, or using the paid solution of chilkat..

Comment: If you are going to shell out to an executable, I'd recommend bzip2 and gnu tar. http://www.bzip.org/ http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/